# Tableau Segmentation

Tags: tableau-api, image-segmentation

I have a question regarding segmentation. I have data for customer purchases at a company going back 4 years (48 months). I'm trying to segment these customers by how much they purchase every month. If they buy $5 worth, I want to group them into a $1-$10 group, a $11-20 group for those in that range, and a $20+ group.

I'm hoping that these groups can be dynamic in the sense that the customers inside the group can change given that they purchase different amounts every month. I also want to use these groups for LOD calculations looking at the additional purchases they made over the years. 
I'm struggling making dynamic groups/segments. I know how to do the LOD calculations, but am not sure how to make 3 groups out of 3 different filters for $1-$10, $11-$20, etc!

Help!

Comment: Can you share some sample data so we know the structure?

Comment: Billing Date Customer Name Total Bill
1/3/2013 Quick Buy 11
2/4/2013 Quick Buy 3
1/1/2014 Databricks 2
1/2/2014 Quick Buy 52
1/3/2014 Quick Buy 15
1/4/2014 OB Chicken 12
1/6/2014 OB Chicken 3
2/5/2015 Best Buy3/6/2015 Target 3
2/7/2015 Cisco 1
2/12/2015 Handbook 52
2/1/2016 Handbook 125
2/3/2016 Modiva 115
4/5/2016 Modiva 1551
2/6/2016 Asha 6
2/7/2016 Asha 126
7/8/2016 Asha 12
7/9/2016 Asha 51
2/10/2016 Asha 2
1/1/2017 Asha 112
1/2/2017 Asha 52
1/3/2017 Mumm 1252
1/4/2017 Mumm 2524
1/5/2017 Gallo 2552
1/6/2017 Gallo 242
1/7/2017 Cline 24

Comment: 3 columns: 1 for the date, 2nd for the company, 3rd for total bill.
For example, 
1/1/2014, Databricks, $10
...
...
1/5/2015, Bobs Burgers, $30
10/2/2015, Databricks $50